# How do i draw a line in visual studios 2015 update 1 C# blank app UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I have windows iot core on raspberri pi 2 and i want to make apps for it and starting simply at drawing a line. I am already stumped.

I went to microsofts website after searching for "how to draw a line xaml uwp"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.line.aspx#constructors

I copy pasted their code using visual studios 2015

```
   <Canvas Height="300" Width="300">
  <!- - Draws a diagonal line from (10,10) to (50,50). - ->
  <Line
   X1="10" Y1="10"
   X2="50" Y2="50"
   Stroke="Black"
   StrokeThickness="4" />
```

I then noticed all the errors.

Error CS1519 Invalid token '<' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Error CS1002; expected

Error CS1519 Invalid token '=' in class, struct or interface member declaration

Error CS1519 Invalid token '=' in class, struct or interface member declaration

My logic here is that the windows core can run any xaml uwp application. So, I should be able to code in Visual studios using C#  windows blank app UWP.

Thanks for your time

My end goal is to have a real time graphing for temperature from my arduino.

Comment: Sounds like you're not using the correct file format.

Comment: there are additional spaces in the xml comment (near hyphen char). change it like `<!-- Draws a diagonal line from (10,10) to (50,50). -->`

Comment: Thanks so much. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the code to mainpage.cs and that was the incorrect place

entering code under the design view panel worked.

```
<Page
x:Class="App10.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App10"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Canvas Height="1000" Width="1000">

        <Line
X1="0" Y1="1000"
X2="1000" Y2="0"
Stroke="Black"
StrokeThickness="4" />


    </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxKLE.jpg